# Please help me debug this simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't get it...my pictures won't load, they're in the same folder

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Animal</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var timeout;
function preLoadImages()
{
if(document.images)
{
animal = new Array();
animal[0] = new Image();
anmial[0] = "bear.jpg";
animal[1] = new Image();
anmial[1] = "duck.jpg";
animal[2] = new Image();
anmial[2] = "elephant.jpg";
animal[3] = new Image();
anmial[3] = "lion.jpg";
animal[4] = new Image();
animal[4] = "cat.jpg";
}
else
alert("There are no images to load");
}
function startSlideShow()
{
if(i < animal.length)
{
document.images["animal_pic"].src = animal[i];
i++;
}
else
{
i =0;
document.images["animal_pic"].src = animal[i];
}
timeout = setTimeout('startSlideSHow()', 3000);
}
function stopSlideShow()
{
clearTimeout(timeout);
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFF00" onLoad = "preLoadImages()">
<img name="animal_pic" height="300" width="300"/>
<form>
<br/><br/>
<input type=button value="Start Show" onClick="return startSlideShow();"/>
<input type=button value="Stop Show" onClick="return stopSlideShow();"/></form>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the developer console in the browser. Any JS errors? Any network errors?

Comment: Typo aside, why do you assign each array element twice?

Comment: Because he doesn't realize he has to assign to the `src` property of that Image he just created, rather than what he's currently doing -- which is replacing it with a string?

Answer (score 3):

You have created the animal array, but stored the value in anmial, spell mistake and also you have to set teh src property...

Wrong:

```
animal[0] = new Image();
anmial[0] = "bear.jpg";
```

Correct:

```
animal[0] = new Image();
animal[0].src = "bear.jpg";
```

Comment: `animal[0] = new Image();` is useless.

Comment: @JonKoops: Are you saying that it won't preload the first image once you set the `src` properly?

Comment: I'm saying if you replace the same index of an array with another value, it really won't do anything with the Image Object.

Comment: @JonKoops: Did you actually read the answer?  Part of the answer is setting the `src` rather than overwriting the image.

Comment: Although that does also involve altering `startSlideShow` to use the `src` rather than all of `animal[i]`....

Comment: @cHao I see, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see quickly, you are missing a closing bracket there :

```
animal[3] = "lion.jpg";
animal[4] = new Image();
animal[4] = "cat.jpg";
} else {
```

There are also spelling mistakes in the name of your array :

```
anmial[3] = ...
animal[4] = ...
```

Be sure to keep your code tidy before testing...

Comment: The brace you're not seeing isn't missing; someone just can't indent worth a crap.  The brace after the `else` part ends the whole function, not the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created some code that should work:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var currentImage = 0,
        imageElement,
        timer,
        images = [
        'bear.jpg',
        'duck.jpg',
        'elephant.jpg',
        'lion.jpg',
        'cat.jpg'
    ];

    var startSlideShow = function() {

        timer = window.setInterval(nextImage, 3000);
    };

    var stopSlideShow = function() {

        window.clearInterval(timer);
    };

    var nextImage = function() {

        currentImage++;

        if( currentImage == images.length ) {
            currentImage = 0;
        }

        imageElement.src = images[currentImage];
    };

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        imageElement = document.querySelector('img[name="animal_pic"]');
        imageElement.src = images[0];

        startSlideShow();
    });

})();
```

You should really do some basic JavaScript tutorials as there are many errors in your code. Here are some suggestions.

```
// Indent your code, JUST DO IT.
var i = 0;
var timeout;
function preLoadImages() { // This function does not actually preload any images.
if(document.images) // Why would you check if there are images in the document when you're gonna load them manually anyways?
{
animal = new Array(); // Use a literal array, also use the 'var' keyword to declare a new variable.
animal[0] = new Image(); // Why would you need this now?
anmial[0] = "bear.jpg"; // I assume you meant 'animal', still why would you fill the same index again?
animal[1] = new Image(); // Same as above
anmial[1] = "duck.jpg"; // Same as above
animal[2] = new Image(); // Same as above
anmial[2] = "elephant.jpg"; // Same as above
animal[3] = new Image(); // Same as above
anmial[3] = "lion.jpg"; // Same as above
animal[4] = new Image(); // Same as above 
animal[4] = "cat.jpg"; // Same as above
}
else // Missing an opening bracket
alert("There are no images to load"); // Yes there are, regardless of document.images.
// Missing closing bracket
}
function startSlideShow()
{
if(i < animal.length) 
{
document.images["animal_pic"].src = animal[i];
i++;
}
else
{
i =0;
document.images["animal_pic"].src = animal[i];
}
timeout = setTimeout('startSlideSHow()', 3000); // This should have a function as a parameter not a string, also there is a typo.
}
function stopSlideShow()
{
clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: Nice pedantry and nitpicking.  I note that you haven't made any attempt to actually solve the problem, though.  Or if you have, it failed miserably.

Comment: Nice to see your answer @cHao

Comment: He asked us to help debugging, here are my corrections.

Comment: Except that you haven't corrected anything whatsoever.  All of your "corrections" are comments, and 95% are syntactic fluff.  The only things worth mentioning were the misspelled names.

Comment: @cHao And where is your contribution?

Comment: In the comments and votes on every answer here.  There's more to contributing than just posting an answer.

Comment: @cHao So what if my corrections are comments, I don't see a problem with that. Don't get all mad about it.

Comment: I wouldn't have gotten annoyed about it if the first sentence of your answer hadn't been "Do some basic JavaScript tutorials."  Rudeness is bad, but if you're gonna be rude, your answer had better be *perfect*.

Comment: For reference, your selector should probably be `img[name="animal_pic"]`.

Comment: @cHao I know, I'm just a bit grumpy today. My apologies. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

```
  animal[4] = "cat.jpg";
    }
    else
    alert("There are no images to load");
    }
    function startSlideShow()
```

you have two closing curly braces and none to open `else alert(` i think you to either change or add a opening one before

```
else
alert("There are no images to load");
```

to either a opening curly brace or just get rid of it

Comment: The braces are correct.  Adding one, or taking away one, would cause a syntax error.  I'd recommend adding a pair of braces around the `else` contents for consistency's sake, but above all i'd recommend he learn to indent properly...which would have kept at least a couple of people from chasing their tails here.